# Does the Diophantine equation $z_1^5 +z_2^5+z_3^5+z_4^5+z_5^5=\beta^5$ have a solution for every integer $\beta$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

*(Note: The exponent $k=3$ has been answered in the **affirmative** in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4760819/4781).)*

---

**I. Data**

For simplicity, assume all terms  $\in \mathbb{Z},$ so we can transform the equation to the more symmetric,

$$x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5 = y_1^5+y_2^5+y_3^5$$

where $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (y_1, y_2, y_3)$ are considered **trivial** solutions. In 2009, by an exhaustive search, Duncan Moore found roughly [5400 **primitive** solutions](https://web.archive.org/web/20160324155057/http://homepage.ntlworld.com/duncan-moore/taxicab/3_3_5.txt) within a search radius of about $17700.$ For example,

\begin{align}
1^5 & + 89^5 + 118^5  = 123^5 + 47^5 + 38^5\\ 
2^5 & + 97^5 + 258^5   = 257^5 + 125^5 + 35^5\\ 
3^5 & + 54^5 + 62^5  = 67^5 + 28^5 + 24^5\\
4^5 & + 32^5 + 498^5   = 463^5 + 369^5 + 302^5\\ 
5^5 & + 145^5 + 224^5    = 214^5 + 157^5 + 153^5 \\
6^5 & + 265^5+ 614^5 = 543^5+ 527^5+ 235^5\\ 
7^5 & + 201^5+ 303^5  = 307^5+ 173^5+ 31^5\\ 
8^5 & + 62^5+ 68^5 \,=\, 74^5+ 43^5+ 21^5\\  
9^5 & + 206^5+ 430^5 = 418^5+ 297^5+ 20^5\\ 
10^5 & + 100^5+ 972^5  = 951^5+ 617^5+ 204^5\\
\vdots\\[4pt]
200^5 & +  334^5 + 676^5  = 679^5 +  256 ^5 +  185^5   
\end{align}

up to $x_1 = 200$ which is quite a *long* stretch. But there were three missing: namely $x_1 = (22,\,88,\,176)$,  all of which are multiples of $11$ and a power of $2$.

*Update*: The list for $0\leq x_1\leq 1000$ is now **complete**, with the last two, namely ($410, 840$), found by Oleg567. See his answer below.

---

**II. Updates**

1. As Adam Bailey pointed out, there doesn't seem to be an obvious congruence obstruction for $x_1 = 22$ and others. So it may be possible for **all** $x_1$ just like its cousin $z_1^3+z_2^3 = z_4^3+z_4^3$ (though by FLT, this has no $z_1 = 0$).
2. There is $0^5  + 220^5 + 14132^5 = 14068^5 + 6237^5 + 5027^5$, so $x_1=0$ is now possible for $5$th powers.
3. Oleg567 found $x_1=176$ valid for $k=1,5$ using a larger search radius,
   $$176^5+20117^5+22952^5=5781^5+12692^5+24772^5$$
   $$176+20117+ 22952=5781+12692+24772$$
4. Moore found $x_1=22$ also valid for $k=1,5.$ (See his answer below.)
5. Using the form ($5,2,4$), wxffles found $x_1=88$ and $x_1=858$ valid only for $k=5.$ (See addendum to Moore's answer for $x_1<1000$.)
6. James Waldby's database for ($5,1,5$) can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230305075640/https://pat7.com/jp/s515-10007-t) for other missing $x_1$.

---

**III. Question**

Can we in fact find a primitive solution $\in \mathbb{Z}$ for **any** integer $x_1$,

$$x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5 = y_1^5+y_2^5+y_3^5$$

hence the absence of $x_1 = 22, 88, 176,$ etc. is simply an artifact of the search radius?

Comment: It is not unnatural that $11$ is problematic prime divisor because every fifth power is congruent to either $0$ or $\pm1\pmod{11}$. Not a prohibitive obstruction, but it does follow that if one of the $x_i$s is a multiple of $11$ then one of the other variables must also be divisible by $11$. My intuition about such equations is undeveloped, but such a constraint may at least make it more difficult to find solutions.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I had a feeling that it was more than coincidence the three missing $x_1$ were divisible by $11$. I will wait if someone will venture an answer.

Comment: Just a quick comment we can introduce $$a^5x^{25}+b^5x^{20}+c^5x^{15}+d^5x^{10}+e^5x^5=f^5$$ and use algoritm related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial

Comment: I noticed that for some equations (more than one) above that $a+b+c=d+e +f$. For example, the first equation: $1+89+118=208=123 + 47 + 38$. But also $8+ 62 + 68= 138=74+ 43+21$. I don't know if it's just a coincidence or something more meaningful.

Comment: @user25406 I meant almost 60% of the solutions in Moore's database will also obey $a+b+c = d+e+f$. The phenomenon has been observed by others, but the large percentage is unexplained as of yet.

Comment: @user25406 For any $n$ we have $n^5-n=n(n^4-1)=(n-1)n(n+1)(n^2+1)$ which is always $\equiv 0 \pmod{30}$.  Hence $a+b+c \equiv d+e+f \pmod{30}$ which, for relatively small values, greatly increases the likelihood that $a+b+c=d+e+f$.

Comment: @AdamBailey There really is no congruence obstruction that forbids $x_1 = 22$, is there? I believe it is just an artifact of the search radius. For $3$rd powers here, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4760819/4781 and with a search radius of $10^6$, I confirmed it for all $x_1<3000$ and only stopped there because I got tired.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII  I agree, there doesn't seem to be any congruence obstruction to $x_1=22$.  And Moore's database does include a solution with $x_1=44$.  It would be an unusual sort of restriction that blocked the former but not the latter.

Comment: $176$ requires simply larger search radius:
$$
176^5+20117^5+22952^5=5781^5+12692^5+24772^5$$
($20117$ is prime number, so the solution is trivial).

Comment: @Oleg567 Thanks! And you mean the solution is "primitive" (not trivial). I'll update the post. How did you find it? Did you form $a^5+b^5+c^5 =N$ with $0\leq a\leq b\leq c$ and check which $N$ appears twice?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, oops yes "primitive", sure. I expected to find solution of the form $$176^5+a^5+b^5=(11x)^5+c^5+d^5,$$where $a \ne 0 (\bmod 11)$, $b \ne 0 (\bmod 11)$. So I formed the set of  $a^5+b^5=N$, where $0\le a \le b$ and checked if the running difference of 2 elements of the set equals to $(11x)^5 - 176^5$ (for given $x$).

Comment: @Oleg567 Ah, clever. Were $22$ and $88$ harder to find?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, yes, at least I didn't find any solution (of the above form) for $22, 88$ inside the search radius $30000$.

Comment: @Oleg567 I think your algorithm can be tweaked for $$11^5(0^5 + 20^5) + 14132^5 = 11^5(457^5 + 567^5) + 14068^5$$ I assume? Its other congruences involving $2^5$ [are here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1072867/4781). If you can find another primitive with a _zero_ term, then I'll ask a question for it. (The last one was found in 1998, so I think we can do better now.)

Comment: @Oleg567 I asked [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4761287/4781) anyway.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I used your comment on pairs of terms being multiples of $11$ to notice that it applied to all three known solutions with $x_1 = 0$. Kindly see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4761287/4781).

Comment: In 2017 I extended my exhaustive search to a radius of 52586. There are 15904 solutions. 8677 (54.6%) have $x+y+z=u+v+w$ also.

In 2017/2018 I ran a separate exhaustive search of the same equation under the constraint $x+y+z=u+v+w\le205848$, giving
16460 solutions, many of which are larger than those in the first set.
This solution has a 22 term: $51233^5 + 36563^5 + 3542^5 = 49013^5 + 42303^5 + 22^5$.

The smallest terms still missing are: 88 275 410 495 785 800 840 850 858.

Comment: @DuncanMoore Hi there Duncan, it's been a while. Can you convert your comment into a partial answer so I can upvote it? Also so that it won't get buried in the comment section. Great to get some new data!

Comment: @Oleg567 Duncan Moore found the case $x_1 = 22.$ Kindly see his answer below.

Comment: Is a more symmetric form important?  Because you can have $88^5 = 28^5 + 198^5 - 188^5 - 134^5 - 116^5 = 215^5 + 263^5 - 271^5 - 175^5 - 154^5 = 335^5 + 298^5 + 140^5 + 132^5 - 367^5$

Comment: @wxffles The symmetric form (5,3,3) is not really essential to the conjecture. Moore focused on it since (I assume) it is easier to create tables for it, though the symmetric form has the interesting side-effect that a lot of solutions are valid for both $k=1,5$. Yours, for example, is only valid for $k=5$. I'll edit the post to include your result. Did you create an exhaustive table for (5,2,4)?

Comment: I wouldn't call it exhaustive. Apparently numbers just keep going on forever! Madness.  I wrote some quick an dirty code to look through up to 400, getting 100ish matches.  I'll tidy it up and send you a table.  (Maybe filter out those non-primitive ones too).

Comment: @wxffles I meant exhaustive below a bound. Anyway, combining Moore's and Waldby's databases, only five remain missing: $410,800,840,850,858$ Are these in your table?

Comment: Since the form $(5,2,4)$ is allowed, then (for example) $22$ and $176$ belong to much smaller solutions:
$$\color{orchid}{22}^5+169^5+471^5+898^5= 724^5+836^5,$$
$$\color{orchid}{176}^5+707^5+713^5+778^5=411^5+913^5.$$

Comment: @Oleg567 I guess the most general form would be ($5,0,6$) or  $$x_1^5+x_2^5+\dots+x_6^5 = 0$$ and the post did specify that terms are $\in \mathbb{Z}$ so any of the forms will do. But ($5,3,3$) in positive integers does have a curiosity: within Moore's bounds, more than 50% are valid for both $k=1,5.$ While ($5,2,4$) and within wxffles's bounds, only 34% are for $k=1,5.$ For ($5,1,5$) within Waldby's bounds, if I remember correctly, none are valid for both $k=1,5.$ This curiosity extends to ($6,3,3$) which is even more pronounced. I'll post a new question for 6th powers soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a partial answer. There is a solution to $x_1 =22$, namely,

$$22^5+42303^5+49013^5=51233^5+36563^5+3542^5$$
$$22+42303+49013=51233+36563+3542$$

---

**I. Extended searches**

In 2017 I extended my previous exhaustive search (2009) of $x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5=y_1^5+y_2^5+y_3^5$ to a radius of $52586$ (i.e. the sum searched to is $52586^5$). There are 15904 solutions and more than half (54.6%) also satisfy $x_1+x_2+x_3=y_1+y_2+y_3$.

In 2017/2018 I ran a separate exhaustive search of the same equation under the constraint $x_1+x_2+x_3=y_1+y_2+y_3\le205848$, giving 16460 solutions, many of which are larger than those in the first set.

The first extended search eliminates 176, as already found by Oleg567. The second search eliminates 22.

---

**II. Statistics**

Given $x_1^k+x_2^k+x_3^k=y_1^k+y_2^k+y_3^k$, statistics for the first extended search are,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Radius} & \text{Solns k = 5} & \text{Solns k = 1,5}   &  \text{% of k = 1,5} & \text{% diff} \\
\hline
  13146  &  3957  &  2378  &  60.1 & --\\
\hline
  26293  &  8108  &  4657  &  57.4 & 2.7\\
\hline
  39439  &  11982 &  6683  &  55.8 & 1.6\\
\hline
  52586  &  15904 &  8677  &  54.6 & 1.2\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

To explain, for the first radius of 13146, then $2378/3957 = 0.601$, or 60.1% of solutions (solns) are valid for two exponents $k=1,5$. For the highest radius of 52586, this falls to 54.6%. However, the decline (% diff) seems to be slowing down, so whether this converges to some percentage is unknown.

---

**III. Addendum** (*by Piezas*)

In Moore's ($5,3,3$) database, there are only 9 missing terms with $x_1<1000$: $$88, 275, 410, 495, 785, 800, 840, 850, 858$$
But by adding the databases of wxffles, Waldby, and an identity by Sastry, we find,

$$\color{blue}{88}^5 + 367^5 = 335^5 + 298^5 + 140^5 + 132^5$$
$$\color{blue}{495}^5 + 1043^5 = \color{blue}{858}^5 + 864^5 + 795^5 + 71^5$$
and,
$$\color{blue}{275}^5 + 351^5 + 872^5 + 1298^5 + 1855^5 = 1921^5$$
$$\color{blue}{495}^5 + 218^5 + 276^5 + 385^5 + 409^5 = 553^5$$
$$\color{blue}{785}^5 + 1023^5 + 2782^5 + 5407^5 + 5500^5 = 6287^5$$

with the first two from wxffles's ($5,2,4$) database, the last three from James Waldby's ($5,1,5$) [database](https://web.archive.org/web/20230305075640/https://pat7.com/jp/s515-10007-t), while Sastry's 1934 parameterization,

$$(\color{blue}{50 n})^5 + (10 n^3)^5 + (n^5 - 25)^5 + (n^5 + 25)^5 = (n^5 - 75)^5 + (n^5 + 75)^5$$

takes care of $x_1$ that are multiples of $50$. Thus only **two** $x_1<1000$ remain missing: $410, 840$.

Comment: Oleg567 has found the last two, namely $410,840$. See his answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer :

Use :

$$(x+y+z)^5-x^5-y^5-z^5-5(x+y)(z+y)(z+x)(x^2+z^2+y^2+xy+yz+zx)=0$$

Then solve :

$$x+y+z=u+v+w=0,(x+y)(z+y)(z+x)(x^2+z^2+y^2+xy+yz+zx)=(u+v)(w+v)(w+u)(u^2+w^2+v^2+uv+vw+wu)=k$$

The identity is called Lamé identity found on your site @TitoPiezasIII

Another idea :

Let introduce (all the variable are integers):

$$a(x,y,z,u,v)=(x+y+z+u+v)^5-(x-y+z+u+v)^5-(x+y-z+u+v)^5-(x+y+z-u+v)^5-(x+y+z+u-v)^5+(x-y-z+u+v)^5+(x-y+z-u+v)^5+(x-y+z+u-v)^5+(x+y-z-u+v)^5+(x+y-z+u-v)^5+(x+y+z-u-v)^5-(x-y-z-u+v)^5-(x-y+z-u-v)^5-(x+y-z-u-v)^5-(x-y-z+u-v)^5+(x-y-z-u-v)^5=1920xyzuv$$

Then we can pick three solution as $$a^5=b^5+c^5-u^5-v^5-w^5,A^5=B^5+C^5-U^5-V^5-W^5,0=B'^5+C'^5-U'^5-V'^5-W'^5$$

To get another one (it's a kind of telescoping).

The big identity is called Boutin's identity ($n=5$) found again on the site for TitoPiezasIII

Comment: Note that if $x+y+z=0$ then
$$(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xz+yz)=xyz(xy+xz+yz).$$

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Take a look to the accordion .

Answer (score 2):

COMMENT.-In relation with the well-known Waring's Problem, the Chinese mathematician Jung-Run Chen has proven, many years ago, that **all natural numbers** can be represented as the sum of $37$ fifth powers of **natural numbers**. So if you are right, we have for all natural number $\beta$ with $n_i \in \mathbb N,$
$$\beta^5=\sum_{1\le i\le37}n_i^5$$ and also $\beta$ with $z_i \in \mathbb Z,$ $$\beta^5=\sum_{1\le i\le5}z_i^5$$ The required minimum $37$, **necessary to have the result valid for all natural integers**, found by Chen, would be denied for all the $5^{th}$powers. There are reasons to be skeptical, despite you work in $\mathbb Z$ where there is greater operability than in $\mathbb N$.

Comment: It is imperfect to compare the post with Waring's problem, since that limits itself to POSITIVE integers. But if we include ALL integers $\mathbb Z$, then like you said, there is greater "operability", and the number of addends may be reduced. The true inspiration of this post is $a^3+b^3+c^3 = N$ discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1565427/4781) which unfortunately involve large addends. The natural analogy is $a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5+e^5 = N$ but, to avoid large addends, I limited it to $N=\beta^5$. And based on Moore's answer and extended tables, one may do so for any $\beta$.

Answer (score 1):

**Still partial answer** 
(completion of the range $0 \le x_1 \le 1000$)

Missing numbers $410, 840$ (and $800$) are covered by such primitive solutions:

$$\color{orchid}{410}^5+581^5+1462^5+3515^5=2622^5+3346^5,$$
$$\color{orchid}{840}^5+800^5+1052^5+1996^5=27^5+2021^5,$$

Note that the example of primitive solution for $800$:
$$\color{orchid}{800}^5+40^5+801^5+2399^5=799^5+2401^5,$$
is generated by $2$-parameter Sastry's 1934 parameterization (see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation5thPowers.html, formula $(5)$, when $u=1, v=2$).

Some example of primitive solution for $1000$:
$$\color{orchid}{1000}^5+5317^5+5393^5+8527^5=690^5+8837^5.
$$
A much bigger primitive solution for $1000$ could be derived from the parametrization above (when $u=1, v=10$):
$$\color{orchid}{1000}^5 +500000^5+2500001^5+7499999^5  =2499999^5 + 7500001^5.$$

Comment: +1 Wonderful! So it's now complete for $0\leq x_1\leq 1000.$